# Can MSSQLLocalDB be used on production web server?

Tags: sql-server, localdb

Long story but I have a web app that has a SQL Server DB that works fine but also has a ASPNETDB.MDF database (for membership), which has always worked fine under SQL Server 2008. I did an upgrade on the server to SQL Server 2014 and I can no longer access the ASPNETDB.MDF database and get this error:

> the server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 -
>   Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I've modified the connection string to update to what is expected with 2014 and that works fine in a simple console app (I can connect, run SQL commands, etc.) But I have not been able to figure out why I can make it work in production. NOTE: it doesn't even work in a browser on the web server - I get the same error.

Here is my connection string:

```
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|ASPNETDB.MDF;Trusted_Connection=Yes" />
```

Comment: Are you using LocallDB  as the post header says (that is reduced version of SQL Server for single user), or full SQL Server?

Comment: Can you update your question with your connection string?

Comment: I think so, but why would you when you can also use Express Edition with the database? Express will work so much better for this.

Comment: I've spent two years devising workarounds to the various weirdness that arises when one uses LocalDB for a multi-user production application.  We now have dozens of successful production sites running for 18 months, but I just keep waiting for the next funky thing to bite us. I highly recommend using SQL Server Express instead, as other commenters and answerers suggest.  If you're set on using LocalDB anyway, I'd be happy to detail the pitfalls and workarounds I used.    Hint: when they discourage having a shared instance owned by Local System or another built-in account, they aren't kidding!

Comment: I ended up using SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's *possible*... but really, you'll do **much** better installing Sql Server Express Edition on that machine, and then attaching the mdf file to the Express instance.

You'll also need some work to setup security and a few other things, but this puts you back into a more "normal" or typical deployment scenario for a web database. This will also make it much easier to troubleshoot the kind of error seen in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe your Remote Connection is not enabled on Server Side.

You have to make sure that it is enabled.

Here's you some [guide1](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213407669-How-to-enable-remote-connections-to-MS-SQL-server-) and [guide2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) to make it Done

Comment: LocalDB CANNOT accept remote connections. The guides above are for full editions of SQL Server, not for LocalDB

Comment: Well if that's the case, I'm out of luck. But this database has been used in production for several years, sat happily in the App_Data folder with SQL 2008. Moreover, I am using SQL Express 2014.